# mvc controllers should only prepare data and pass it to an appropriate service method call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

Please tell if this is a correct statement:

"Mvc controller's method should have only one call to an appropriate service method, all other statement should just arrange data which is going to be passed to this service method."

Lets say I'm using asp.net core web api and I have an endpoint ('user/register') dedicated to user registration. So it has method inside the controller (lets say UserController or something):

`Registed([FromBody] User user) {...}`.

Is it correct that this method should have only one service method call:

`_userRegistrationService.Register(UserDto user) {...}`

in it and all other statements should just prepare user model and nothing else?

So basically controller only arrange data and pass it to the service method and do nothing else.

This seems logical and mvc-idiomatically correct. So is it?

Comment: When you have a rule that Controllers should not do business logic then yes, this statement is correct.

Comment: but you should have that rule, right? a dedicated service seems like a correct place for business logic and not an api controller's method.

Comment: Yes, it is a good rule.

Comment: Experience has shown that real apps can't be written by the book. So yes, put your business logic in the service, but it's quite possible you'll need to call more than one service from a single controller action. Just keep the controller code down to a minimum.

Comment: @TsahiAsher thinking the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: @TsahiAsher - you can always write a service to call those other services... But I get your point, I wouldn't be too strict about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a much bigger discussion to be fair and the statement cannot be taken out of context.

It is generally good practice to keep controllers very thin and keep all logic in other places.

There are multiple reasons for this, the main one being that it keeps business functionality where it belongs, in its own dedicated place. This then has implications on testing since you no longer have to do all the crazy things un-seasoned developers do, such as instantiating and mocking controllers, calling controller methods to test things when really, if your functionality is decoupled then testing becomes a lot simpler since you can test those separate things in isolation without trying to test the entire MVC framework.

This is generally the context where that statement is correct.

Comment: but you implying that in some context or situations this rule can be violated and still be rational or  idiamatically correct?

Comment: i am implying that it may not necessarily be one  call, there is a difference between thin controller and a one line call

Comment: well yes, obviously this is an extremelly simplified example with one-liner in my initial question, real thing will do much more like logging, verification etc. but the general idea of extracting business logic applies here. In question I meant one call per appropriate service, not just one call at all. Thanks for reply, marked it as an answer.